Minimizing differences when recompiling BusyBox for CorePure64 (TinyCore)
I've encountered an issue while trying to replace the default BusyBox in CorePure64 with a recompiled version. Despite using the default config file busybox-1.36.0_config.nosuid and not enabling any additional features, the differences between my recompiled binary and the original are more extensive than expected.
To analyze the differences, I used the following commands:
objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 ./busybox1 > busybox1.asm
objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 ./busybox5 > busybox5.asm
diff ./busybox1.asm ./busybox5.asm

Although the file sizes remain the same, I observed over 20 discrepancies beyond the anticipated changes in the date string. Here’s how I compiled BusyBox in TinyCore 11.x, as per the instructions:

Setup and Download:
tce-load -i compiletc sstrip
wget https://www.busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.36.0.tar.bz2
cd busybox-1.36.0


Applying Patches:
patch -Np1 -i ../busybox-1.27.1-wget-make-default-timeout-configurable.patch
patch -Np1 -i ../busybox-1.29.3_root_path.patch
patch -Np1 -i ../busybox-1.33.0_modprobe.patch
patch -Np0 -i ../busybox-1.33.0_tc_depmod.patch


Configuration and Compilation:
cp busybox-1.36.0_config.suid .config
make oldconfig
make CC="gcc -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe" CXX="g++ -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"
sudo make CC="gcc -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe" CONFIG_PREFIX=/tmp/pkg install
sudo mv /tmp/pkg/bin/busybox /tmp/pkg/bin/busybox.suid


Recompilation with No SUID:
cp busybox-1.36.0_config.nosuid .config
make oldconfig
make CC="gcc -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe"
sudo make CC="gcc -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe" CONFIG_PREFIX=/tmp/pkg install



Despite following these steps, the number of differences is puzzling. My question to the community: How can I compile BusyBox so that it more closely matches the original BusyBox included with CorePure64? Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated!
